# How do we create a FOR Loop calling an .exe in a specific range?

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to write a batch script that processes a stack of files with an exe file.
I go so far to defining variables, and I got a frame number, but I need to loop the entire sequence over for example frame 1-100 without having to generate 100 lines of entires with each its own frame number.

It looks like this now, and obviously just goes over the same frame over and over again, but it does wait, and continue on next item which is good. I am just missing the FOR loop, I belive it is, but unsure how to implement it.

SET frame= should rather be a range 1-100

I know about /l %%G IN () something...but I cant realy see how to intergrate it.

```
@echo off
SET noice=C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\MAXtoA\noice.exe
SET Path=C:\go\
SET Name=go
SET frame=0003
start /WAIT %noice% -i %Path%%Name%_AOVs%frame%.exr -o 
%Path%%Name%_Denoised%frame%.exr
```

Comment: So you just want to run `start /WAIT /%noice%..` in a loop 100 times?

Comment: Hi Gerhard, practically speaking, I render 100 .exr frames to disk. All ends up being called... "go_AOVs0000.exr -> go_AOVs0100.exr. the script so far handles a single action correctly, does its thing and outputs same name and frame number but with the _Denoised addition, so go_AOVs_0000.exr becomes go_AOVs_Denoised0000.exr. Mind you I am extremly rookie on the field. What you write makes sense, and yes I want to run the exe 100 times grabbing frame 0045 do its thing, and spit out Denoised_0045 as an example then continue to 0046 etc.

Comment: @npocmaka yes, sorry, forgot that switch.

Comment: something like `for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do set "frame=%%i"` ?

Comment: ok, going to attempt an answer, so just test it please.

Comment: Ok let me test it Gerhard, hold on.

Comment: Let me post answer first.

Comment: Ok sorry, Ill wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET "noice=C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\MAXtoA\noice.exe"
SET "MPath=C:\go\"
SET "MName=go"
for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do (
set "frame=%%i"

if !frame! GEQ 100 set "lframe=0!frame!"
if !frame! LEQ 99 set "lframe=00!frame!"
if !frame! LEQ 9 set "lframe=000!frame!"

echo start "" /WAIT %noice% -i %MPath%%MName%_AOVs!lframe!.exr -o %MPath%%MName%_Denoised!lframe!.exr
)
```

Comment: hold a sec, this will set frame `1`..`100` and not `0001` to `0100`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I recorded a GIF showing the result and my folder containing 7 files, obviously changed the roof to 7.
See it here https://i.imgur.com/GhAdGP1.gif
As you can see, it opens 7 windows quicly and closes them down again. If the noice catches first frame correctly, it should initiate a process that takes about 2-3 seconds, then continue to the next, this does not happen. I am not able to determin the cause of the rapid spawning windows, and no actual processing. I should note that noice.exe does exsist at the location but also just happens to exsist in this folder shown.

Comment: ok, will look at that now, perhaps it is because the frames are 1 - 100 and not 0001 - 0100

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YdElw93.gif Here you can see what I am expecting when running it manually.

Comment: @Benny run the edited script please, it should echo the result only and not the actual command, make sure it is giving the wanted result, then we will move to the other issue if still exist.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/RX0FYdn.gif This is the modified script Gerhard, it looks like we are indexing files up to 100.

Comment: Awesome! it is working Gerhard. I will now attempt to give you points, and rewards to full extend. Thank you very much.

Comment: @benny Ok awesome. Thanks

Comment: I'd use an offset of 10000 and keep only the last 4 digits. No IFs needed then.

Comment: Im trying to understand what you mean, will look up offset at a point.